# how about to use encodeURIComponent to encode key and parameter

Tags: typescript, http

when I using encodeURIComponent like this:

```
export function getDownloadFileUrl(fid: string,bgColor: string) {
    const params = encodeURIComponent("id=" + Number(fid) + "&bgColor=" + bgColor);
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: '/snap/photo/download?' + params,
    };
    const actionTypeString: string = FileActionType[FileActionType.DOWNLOAD_FILE];
    return requestWithActionType(config, actionTypeString, store);
}
```

the server side shows could not received the id parameter(id parameter is missing). Am I missing something? I read the document and told that encodeURIComponent used to encode parameters. what should I do to fixed it? the encodeURIComponent only used to encode the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `encodeURIComponent` not *encodeEntireQueryStringInOneGo*.

It converts characters with special meaning to encoded versions. This lets you use those characters as data instead of as having their special meaning. If you convert all the `=` (which links a name to its value) and the `&` (which mark the end of one name=value pair and the start of the next one) then you break the data format.

```
const params = "id=" + encodeURIComponent(Number(fid)) + "&bgColor=" + encodeURIComponent(bgColor);
```

That said, we now have [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which will generate the whole query string for you (i.e. insert `=` and `&` and escape as needed).

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({
    id: Number(fid),
    bgColor
});
```